# Improve table recognition

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

i try to analyze invoices with the form-recognizer and the labeling tool.The invoices contain fields and table data. All data within the tables are recognized by the ocr process and readable.
Unfortunately the tables are not always recognized as tables. Sometimes only half of the data is recognized as table, in some cases there is nothing tagged as table.

What is the best way to get the table data?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool) says:
"Table data should be detected automatically and will be available in the final output JSON file. However, if the model fails to detect all of your table data, you can manually tag these fields as well. **Tag each cell in the table with a different label.** If your forms have tables with varying numbers of rows, make sure you tag at least one form with the largest possible table."

This is inpractical and would bumb the fieldcounter above a few hundred fields.
Is there a way to improve the table recognition, maybe by modifying the labels.json and define [regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/python-labeled-data#create-the-label-files)?

Comment: Thanks Mike for the feedback. Could you please share some sample data if that's not confidential so that we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

If the sample invoice and tables are complex due to the scan quality and a complex table and these tables are currenlty not automatically detected by our table extraciton. We are working on improving our table technology and hope to be able to extract complex tables in the near future.

As a workaround until then you can try and use the Form Recognizer train with labels feature and label these tables as key value pairs, labeling each cell of the table as a value. Please note you will need to label and train with 5 samples with the maximum number of rows in the tables.